# Simple Java type based on String

Tags: java

I'd like a simple way of generating a type safe type based on String.

I have a bunch of places where I usually use just a String to hold opaque UID (example) and I'd like to move away from this.

`java.lang.String` is final. Ideally I would have liked to extend `String` but I understand I can't be doing that.  What are my best options?

I know I can use an encapsulation but I am looking for something a bit more efficient, if at all possible.

*Update*: I want a meaningful name for the type i.e. not just UUID everywhere.

Comment: Why not just have it as a private member?

Comment: Why not just use a class like [java.util.UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)?

Comment: @Roddy: because I want to have a meaningful name for the type.

Comment: if i may ask, what would you name the type? mySuperSpecialUUID? i don't see the significance in wrapping a type just to give it a new name.

Comment: I just want to be as close as a String as possible without the overhead of another type... just to carry a String.

Comment: Sorry, I see no value in this whatsoever.  If I were working on this project with you, I'd do all I could to discourage this idea.  If I were a user of your library, I'd despise you for a do-nothing choice.

Comment: @duffymo: I am starting to think this whole idea is, like you say, a bad one.

Comment: What is the protocol here?  Should I just delete the question altogether???

Answer (score 3):

String inherits from [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

If change your reference type CharSequence, you can use StringBuilder or any other mutable CharSequence.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Because `String` is declared `final`, I think encapsulation is the only thing you can do. To provide some level of plug-compatibility, you can declare your class to implement `CharSequence`.

```
public class TypeSafeStringBase implements CharSequence {
    protected final String mString;
    protected TypeSafeStringBase(String string) {
        mString = string;
    }
    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return mString.charAt(index);
    }
    @Override
    public int length() {
        return mString.length();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mString.subSequence(start, end);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mString;
    }
}

public class ParamName extends TypeSafeStringBase {
    ParamName(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
}

public class Prompt extends TypeSafeStringBase {
    Prompt(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
}

// etc.
```

You might consider also declaring the base class to implement `Serializable` and `Comparable<String>` (or a type-safe `Comparable` for each subclass).